# Is there a way to communicate synchronously between two EARs using SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rmi

I have two EARs which are deployed on a single Weblogic server. The two EARs are A and B.

"A" has a service that "B" needs to access. B needs to access this service and get the data synchronously.

I do not want to use REST or other HTTP methods as it would slow down the communication.

**Is there something like RMI for SpringBoot that works within the Same server?**

**Or is it equally faster to use a REST call within the same server compared to an RMI based solution?**

I went through Spring Remote, but it seems to be for communication between different servers. Please let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Why would Spring Remote be for communicating between different servers. It is for communicating, remotely, to another application. This application can be on the same server.

Comment: You can use JMS. Though it is mostly asynchronous you can tweak to make it synchronous.